# sed command not giving proper output for regular expression used

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to fetch data between a range of time intervals from the log file. However, the complete data is not fetched for the end date.

Below is the command used:

```
 sed -n '/26/Nov/2018/,/30/Nov/2018/ p' /path/file.log
```

The data I am having in the above log file is somewhat like:

```
 192.168.0.123 - - [25/Nov/2018:13:24:59 +0530] "Data 1"
 192.168.0.123 - - [26/Nov/2018:13:24:59 +0530] "Data 2"
 192.168.0.123 - - [26/Nov/2018:13:25:09 +0530] "Data 3"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:09 +0530] "Data 4"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:11 +0530] "Data 5"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 6"
 192.168.0.123 - - [28/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 7"
 192.168.0.123 - - [29/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 8"
 192.168.0.123 - - [30/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 9"
 192.168.0.123 - - [30/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 10"
 192.168.0.123 - - [01/Dec/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 11"
 192.168.0.123 - - [01/Dec/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 12"
```

Comment: That should give you a syntax error. Please remember to always include any errors you get in your question.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `/` both as a separator for the sed match command and as part of the string being matched. You need to escape the internal `/`. Try this instead:

```
$  sed -n '/26\/Nov\/2018/,/30\/Nov\/2018/ p' file.log 
 192.168.0.123 - - [26/Nov/2018:13:24:59 +0530] "Data 2"
 192.168.0.123 - - [26/Nov/2018:13:25:09 +0530] "Data 3"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:09 +0530] "Data 4"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:11 +0530] "Data 5"
 192.168.0.123 - - [27/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 6"
 192.168.0.123 - - [28/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 7"
 192.168.0.123 - - [29/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 8"
 192.168.0.123 - - [30/Nov/2018:13:25:53 +0530] "Data 9"
```

Comment: Hi @terdon. Sorry I had posted the question removing the backslashes. The problem I am facing is, if the end date is not matching with any date in the file, then it is fetching all the logs till the end of the file. Is there a way to stop it till the date before the date where the data is not present?